# Service application in Delphi

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I am struggling with service application in Delphi but no major success so far. I tried to recreate [this project](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Delphi-Kylix/Creating-a-Windows-Service-in-Delphi/4/), but it doesn't seem to work properly. File is created, but date and time aren't added to file every 10 seconds. I also don't see a message popping up from my ShowMessage. I successfully install and start service application.

Here is my code:

```
unit TMS;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.SvcMgr, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TWorkflow = class(TService)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ServiceBeforeInstall(Sender: TService);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Workflow: TWorkflow;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  Workflow.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TWorkflow.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.ServiceBeforeInstall(Sender: TService);
begin
  Interactive := True;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(True);
  end;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
  FileName = 'D:\Projekti\EMBRACADERO\TMSWorkflow\Win32\Debug\Log.txt';
var
  F : TextFile;
begin
  AssignFile(F, FileName);
  if FileExists(FileName) then
    Append(F)
  else
    Rewrite(F);
  Writeln(F, DateTimeToStr(Now), ' ', DiskFree(0));
  ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(Now));
  CloseFile(F);
end;

end.
```

Could somebody give me an example of a service application with threads maybe or service with visual components included?

UPDATE1:

It is working with following code for inserting some data in database every 3 seconds.

```
private
    thread : TThread;  

procedure TWorkflow.InsertInDatabase;
begin
  FDTransaction1.StartTransaction;
  try
    FDQuery1.Execute;
    FDTransaction1.Commit;
  except
    FDTransaction1.Rollback;
  end;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);
    InsertInDatabase();
    thread.sleep(3000);
  end;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
  thread := TThread.Create;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  FreeAndNil(thread);
end;
```

Comment: Services don't show UI. You need to get a better picture of what services do before proceeding.

Comment: Why do you expect a service to be able to make audible sounds? Your real problem is that you don't know what a service is. Isn't it time to rectify that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can service update table in database?

Comment: Sure, that's no problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I made it working. Is my update OK or is there some good practise I'm not aware of.

Comment: @skafinski Your thread instead don't do anything. Just get rid of this unused class instance, and use plain Sleep() function.

Comment: Yes, the thread seems pointless as it stands. Are you still using VCL units? The catch all exception handler looks bad.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez How could I use my thread. Where do i need to put it so it will do all the work(executing SQLs)  |||||

David - no. Only non-visual component like fdquery, fdconnection...why? For exception should I do on Except E do (write in file).?

Comment: @skafinski 1. TWorkflow.ServiceExecute is run within the main thread of the service process, once started. Your TThread is not used at all. 2. For security reasons, UI is not available from a service, since Vista - so you can't use the VCL from a service. You have to handle exceptions within your service, without any user interaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TTimer` code you showed is fine (though your `OnExecute` event is redundant can should be completely removed), *except for* the call to `ShowMessage()`, which you cannot use in a service at all (the `TService.Interactive` property has no effect on Windows Vista+).  If you must display a popup message box from a service (which you should strive not to), you must use the Win32 API `MessageBox()` with the `MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION` flag specified, or use `WTSSendMessage()` instead.  Otherwise, you have to delegate any UI to a separate non-service process that the service spawns and/or communicates with as needed.

Your `TThread` code, on the other hand, is completely wrong.  It should be more like this instead:

```
unit TMS;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.SvcMgr;

type
  TWorkflowThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

  TWorkflow = class(TService)
    FDTransaction1: TFDTransaction;
    FDQuery1: TFDQuery;
    procedure ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceShutdown(Sender: TService);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    thread: TWorkflowThread;
    procedure InsertInFile;
    procedure InsertInDatabase;
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Workflow: TWorkflow;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  Workflow.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TWorkflow.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.InsertInFile;
const
  FileName = 'D:\Projekti\EMBRACADERO\TMSWorkflow\Win32\Debug\Log.txt';
var
  F : TextFile;
begin
  try
    AssignFile(F, FileName);
    try
      if FileExists(FileName) then
        Append(F)
      else
        Rewrite(F);
      Writeln(F, DateTimeToStr(Now), ' ', DiskFree(0));
      //ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(Now));
    finallly
      CloseFile(F);
    end;
  except
  end;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.InsertInDatabase;
begin
  try
    FDTransaction1.StartTransaction;
    try
      FDQuery1.Execute;
      FDTransaction1.Commit;
    except
      FDTransaction1.Rollback;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
  thread := TWorkflowThread.Create(False);
  Started := True;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  ServiceShutdown(Sender);
  Stopped := True;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.ServiceShutdown(Sender: TService);
begin
  if Assigned(thread) then
  begin
    thread.Terminate;
    while WaitForSingleObject(thread.Handle, WaitHint-100) = WAIT_TIMEOUT do
      ReportStatus;
    FreeAndNil(thread);
  end;
end;

procedure TWorkflowThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    Workflow.InsertInFile;
    Workflow.InsertInDatabase;
    TThread.Sleep(3000);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your timer code will not execute because timers rely on a window handle and message pump that `TService` does not provide. Furthermore, `TTimer` is not thread-safe because in uses the VCL's `AllocateHwnd()` function which is not thread-safe and should not be used outside the context of the main thread. Generally, when writing service applications you would spawn a worker thread to perform the main logic.

If you need a thread-safe timer, I would suggest you use a different timer mechanism, such as `WaitForSingleObject()`

Assitionally, services should not contain any visual controls as they should not interact with the desktop at all.

Comment: Do you maybe have and example of that kind of service. What can you do then in Windows service? Can you do stuff in database? can you catch post events with eventAlerter?

Comment: In this case, the `TTimer` is a child of a `TService` object that is created in the context of the main thread at process startup but is used in the context of a worker thread at service startup. So the `TTimer` will run in the context of the main thread, not the service thread. `TServiceApplication.Run()` does actually run in message loop in the main thread, so the `TTimer` events will actually work. But you have to make sure its code is thread-safe (which in this case, it is, except for the `ShowMessage()`, which does not work in a service).

Answer (score 1):

> Could somebody give me an example of service application with threads.

If your code is doing all its work in a thread, you are almost done.

Just start your thread in the service start event. For debugging, run the thread in a small (console) program.

Instead of a timer, let your main thread sleep for a while.

Comment: procedure TWorkflow.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);
    Beep;
    thread.sleep(3000);
  end;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
  thread := TThread.Create;
end;

procedure TWorkflow.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  FreeAndNil(thread);
end;

Comment: @skafinski there is no need for `ServiceExecute` to do anything with your thread. As I wrote, put all your code inside your thread, do not communicate with the service environment. Keep it simple.